# Найти до 3 самых больших числа из списка в Python

Tags: python

Имеется несколько списков с числами, допустим: [31, 44, 12, 3, -1], [12, 2], [], из них нужно вернуть до 3 самых больших чисел ([31, 44, 12], [12,2], []), не нарушая последовательности, как это сделать?

Comment: допустим вы предположили 3 списка, а можете допустить конкретный получаемый ответ на эти списки? И где ваши попытки что-то написать, у вас есть?

Comment: создаёшь три переменные равные, проходишь по спискам с условием: если текущий элемент больше переменной1 то переменная1 равна этому числу, переменная2 равна предыдущему значению переменной1

Comment: из первых трех чисел создать список с максимумами и запомнить наименьший из них и индекс этого числа в списке. Далее идти по списками и сверять каждое число с этим наименьшим. Если будет больше, заменить его на новый, определив новый наименьший минимум.

Comment: что нужно вернуть из приведенных нескольких списков и в каком виде?

Comment: исправил с учетом требуемых ответов

Comment: и буду благодарен за ответ с примером, ибо сам еще совсем новичок)

Comment: Что надо вернуть для списка `[3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1]`?

Comment: полагаю [3, 3, 2], никаких точных наводок по этому поводу нет

Answer (score 2):

Тяжёлая артиллерия. Три самых больших значения из списка собираем в множество. Список фильтруем относительного этого множества, выбираем три первых элемента:

```
import heapq
import itertools


def largest(lst, n):
    s = set(heapq.nlargest(n, lst))
    return list(itertools.islice((v for v in lst if v in s), n))
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется все гораздо проще.

```
#допустим ты засунешь все списки в один
all_lists = [list1,list2,list3]
reversed_result = []
for list in all_lists:
    reversed_result.append(sorted(list, reverse=True)[:3])
```

Вот и все дела)

Comment: "не нарушая последовательности"?